# keccak3 in SOLIDITY and in WEB3 different hashes for an address type field

Tags: solidity, hash, keccak

How can I get the same resulting hash from Keccak-256 ()in solidity and web3.sha3() in web3?

IN solidity using keccak256( address ) and using web3.sha3 ( address ) gives different results.

In web3 the address field is a string while in solidity it is an address.

How can I convert web3 string to an address type field?

I tried converting the address type field to a string in solidity and I still received different results in hashes.

For address to sting in solidity I used

```
function toString(address x) returns (string) {
    bytes memory b = new bytes(20);
    for (uint i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        b[i] = byte(uint8(uint(x) / (2**(8*(19 - i)))));
    return string(b);
}
```

Comment: @RichardHorrocks this isn't a sha3 vs keccak256 issue, it's an input argument encoding issue, so I don't believe that particular question is a proper duplicate

Comment: Okay, yep, looks like you're probably right - apologies for jumping the gun. +1 :-)

Answer (score 8):

`web3.sha3()` takes an [encoding parameter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3sha3) to specify that you are passing in a hex address:

```
address_string = '0x5b2063246f2191f18f2675cedb8b28102e957458';
web3.sha3(address_string, {encoding: 'hex'});
```

As a general side-note: you have to pay gas costs to do any custom work in Solidity so, when possible, you are best off working on the javascript side.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can perform `keccak256( address )` in a `constant` solidity function locally, and then pass the result into a transaction. Of course, this is not safe for production, if you let users do that in their browser.

Comment: what's the issue with using this for production? it works.

Comment: the resulting hash could be moedified before it gets passed into a transaction. "Don't trust the client" doctrine.

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of web3 has a `web3.utils.soliditySha3` function you can use that mimics Solidity's hashing:

```
address = '0x407D73d8a49eeb85D32Cf465507dd71d507100c1';
hash = web3.utils.soliditySha3(address);
```

Comment: You cannot hash an address in Solidity 0.5.0 anymore

Answer (score 0):

It is often easy to use ABI encoding toolkit that does so called "tight packing" or given arguments. You can perform this with one built-in function.

In Solidity

```
 /**
   * A test method exposed to be called from clients to compare that ABI packing and hashing
   * is same across different programming languages.
   *
   * Does ABI encoding for an address and then calculates KECCAK-256 hash over the bytes.
   *
   * https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3
   *
   */
  function calculateAddressHash(address a) public pure returns (bytes32 hash, bytes memory data) {

    // First we ABI encode the address to bytes.
    // This is so called "tight packing"
    // https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3
    bytes memory packed = abi.encodePacked(a);

    // Then we calculate keccak256 over the resulting bytes
    bytes32 hashResult = keccak256(packed);

    return(hashResult, packed);
  }
```

In JavaScript/TypeScript

```
  import { soliditySha3 } from 'web3-utils';

  // Sign address
  const { signature, v, r, s } = signAddress(user2);

  // This is an address is a hexadecimal format
  const ourData = user2.toLowerCase();

  // https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#id23
  // Convert address to bytes using "tight packing"
  // and them calculates keccak-256 over the resulting bytes
  const ourHash = soliditySha3({t: 'address', v: user2 });

  // We hash data in similar in TypeScript and Solidity
  const { hash, data } = await tokenSwap.calculateAddressHash(user2);
  assert(ourData.toLowerCase() == data.toLowerCase());
  assert(ourHash.toLowerCase() == hash.toLowerCase());
```