# The Solidity 'keccak256' and the Javascript ethers.js 'solidityKeccak256' produces different output

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, keccak, ecdsa

I'm trying to code a signature like opensea does for approving the Terms of Service.
To do so I'm using the ECDSA library.

This code in javascript using ethers:

```
const message = ethers.utils.solidityKeccak256(
  ['address'],
  [
    '0x00cF2CFA50bD1434C65F00Bf80867499492f5639',
  ],
)
console.log(message)
```

Gives me a different output as this code in Solidity:

```
address owner = 0x00cF2CFA50bD1434C65F00Bf80867499492f5639;
bytes32 public message = keccak256(
    abi.encodePacked(owner)
);
```

why is it so?

I checked [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24093/keccak3-in-solidity-and-in-web3-different-hashes-for-an-address-type-field/24098?newreg=1aa98b5f87364c379047ebd783ace4e1) and [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96697/soliditys-keccak256-hash-doesnt-match-web3-keccak-hash) but they don't help me since they use WEB3 and I use ethers.

Comment: What hashes do you have in both cases?

Comment: ethers.js gives:
0x661483957cd349fdb3dba77e9ca622510d2429df42eba774af2c8ebf8fd6fad7

solidity gives:
0x5380c7b7ae81a58eb98d9c78de4a1fd7fd9535fc953ed2be602daaa41767312a

Comment: your address has the wrong checksum, https://ethsum.netlify.app/

Answer (score 2):

Tried this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Test1 {
  address owner = 0x00cF2cfa50BD1434C65f00Bf80867499492F5639;
  bytes32 message = keccak256(
      abi.encodePacked(owner)
  );

  function test() public view returns (bytes32) {
    return message;
  }
}
```

and the result = `0x661483957cd349fdb3dba77e9ca622510d2429df42eba774af2c8ebf8fd6fad7` is the same as for [ethers](http://jsfiddle.net/3xok5bgr/).

Btw solidity says owner's address is not good in terms of checksum. The example fixes that.